# TIP: How to find total number of unique objects among many instances

Tags: instances, outliner

Is there a way to know how many unique objects (with unique mesh data) are in a Blender scene when you have a lot of instances of different objects? For example, if you have a scene with 500 instances of a cube, and 200 instances of a sphere, how would you know that you only had 2 unique objects? Is this number shown somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are two ways to do this! Blender refers to the number of unique objects as "Meshes", so you can find the number of unique meshes present in your scene within the Outliner panel. The first way is to set the Outliner to "Blender File" (highlighted in cyan color below). **The number of unique Mesh IDs is shown as a tiny number beside the Meshes symbol.** This is the total number of non-instanced meshes in your scene. On the other hand, the total number of objects (including instanced meshes) is shown as a tiny number beside the Objects symbol. **In the sample image below, there are only 2 unique meshes in the scene, but a total of 4 objects, since the cube is instanced 3 times.** This question had puzzled me until now, I hope the info helps someone else too. :-)

**EDIT:** **Unfortunately, if you have more than 99 objects in your scene, the tiny number will only say "+99"**, so it's still not terribly useful to determine the total number of objects in your scene. **In this case, you should switch the Outliner to "Data API" mode** (shown in cyan color below). From here, you can see a numerical value for the total number of unique meshes even if it exceeds 99.

[image: Total number of unique objects in Blender]

[image: Total number of unique meshes in Blender]